# How to block the access to folders?

Tags: html, web, block

I have a website, and I want to block the access to the folders and the files.
The structure is something like:

- **www.domain.com/index.html**
- **www.domain.com/images/picture.jpg**

When I search for "www.domain.com/img" in the address bar, I come to a page where I can navigate in the folders and the files of the website.

How can I block it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .htaccess file in your webroot i.e. at domain.com and then add the following lines:

`IndexIgnore /images/*`

The above line will block listing of directories and files at images directory. For other specific file type like jpg you can use IndexIgnore *.jpg

You may also try adding blank index.html page in each directory where you want to remove directory listing.

Comment: It is still send we to a navigate page, but i can't see which file are exist on this folder. When I search for "www.domain.com/img", i want it will send me to "www.domain.com/img". Does it possible?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you clarify a little more?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an Apache webserver you can include an .htacces file with the line

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will tell the server not to show the underlying files and folders

Comment: I don't know if it is Apache webserver. I use 000webhost. How I create this .htacces file?

Comment: When you are logged into 000webhost and in your cpanel, you should be able to see 'File Manager' icon, from where you can see your file manager. And then you can use 'New file' button to create a .htaccess file in  '/public_html

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to .htaccess file in www.domain.com/img directory:

Options -Indexes